# Write line equations with boundaries so that only the area given in the picture would be the answer

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, absolute-value

[Square shapes with equations](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zwvfkwbgzc)

In this graph, I've tried to draw 2 squares. I want to somehow point to the area in between them with equations. How can this be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $$7<|x|+|y|<10$$ for any needed point $(x,y).$

I hope it will help.